# How to suppress TASKILL output in python os module

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, operating-system, py2exe, nuitka

I am trying to create a close button for my tkinter application without using the sys module. I implemented this:

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM main.exe")
```

and converted my program into an exe using Nuitka. Even though I'm using `--windows-disable-console` while creating the exe with Nuitka, it creates a CLI window after the close button is pressed and outputs "SUCCESS: The process "main.exe" with PID (it shows a different number each time) has been terminated." I tried using py2exe as well to convert it but it does the same thing even though i specify that it is a gui application in my setup.py file. How do I prevent it from creating the CLI window and outputting the success message? I've been trying to figure this out for days but I haven't figured out anything which actually works.

Answer (score 0):

You are suppressing the PROGRAM output with `--windows-diable-console`. To disable the output from hte shell, you would have to use the subprocess module

```py
import subprocess
execution_commands_to_be_put_in_popen_to_run = subprocess.Popen(['TASKKILL', '/F', '/IM', 'main.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print(execution_commands_to_be_put_in_popen_to_run.stdout.read())
```